# computer programing and designing- help with javascript codeing

Tags: javascript

I need help with my assignment. I am getting stuck on it. I am suppose to make a javascript code to the following statement, it must have an alert window, else if statement, calculation, and so on. I have tried so many ways to make the alert window work, but I seem to always get a blank page. I am not asking for you to do it for me but to help me start it to get a good idea. Please help me with this it would be nice if I see an example to help me with the main idea. This is the assignment:

> Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling charge for purchases. Create a
>   Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box and includes a
>   JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script
>   that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less
>   than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price
>   for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling
>   charge. The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the
>   formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a
>   shipping and handling charge of $5.00. After you determine the total cost of the order
>   (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box.

Comment: eman, post what you have

Comment: The best thing would be to show what you've got and where you're stuck

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

> The main idea?

When having a big task at hand, which involves many tasks (like if-else logic, counting, alerting etc.), it is best to break the task into pieces and one by one join them together to make the complete assignment. [Javascipt tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) may be helpful for you.

Following is a sample code from that site:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Returns true if a field is non-empty
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
{
  with (field)
  {
    if (value==null||value=="")
    {
      alert(alerttxt);return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
}

function validate_form(thisform)
{
  with (thisform)
  {
    if (validate_required(email,"Email must be filled out!")==false)
    {
       email.focus();return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="submit.htm" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)" method="post">
     E mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="30">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

If this example looks very complex. Try out other easier examples in the w3schools site
**Some tips**
- Start with working codes and edit them to implement what you want.
- Check if your code has errors. Make sure error reporting is on in your browser

You can try running some code here:- [W3c editor](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro)

or [Js Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I am having a hard time figuring out this statement; Add functionality to the script
that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less
than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price
for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling
charge. I can't seem to get it working for some reason. I am always keeping in my mind that I have to have the formula in the alert box. Any help please.

Comment: @Eman This means you need to add an if-else statement to check the purchase amount. if purchase amount less than or equal to $25 add $1.50 to the purchase amount. Put another if condition to check if purchase price is more than $25 - in that case add 10% of the purchase price. You already have the formula with you. Doug's answer gives the code. But I think you should start with simpler codes

Comment: Please can anyone help this is what I have <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculating Shipping and Handling</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//IF YOUR PURCHASE TOTAL IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 25 ADD 1.5 SHIPING AND HANDLING 
//OTHERWISE ADD 10 TO PURCHASED TOTAL PRICE. 
function MsgBox(totalAmount){
alert(totalAmount)}
function totalAmount (){

Comment: @Eman write it in the question.

Comment: I am trying to put everything into one, but it won't let me post it so I have to split it up. I hope you could see the full coding of what I did.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there in the end

Answer (score 1):

This assignment is meant to familiarize you with the idea of hooking up events to HTML objects, with using some of the common operators (multiplication, division, assignment, etc) and to declare functions with parameters, return values, and to use them all together.

Consider the following:

```
function alertTotalAmount() {
  var orderAmount = getOrderAmount();
  var shippingAndHandling = calculateShippingAndHandling(orderAmount);

  var totalAmount = orderAmount + shippingAndHandling;

  alert(totalAmount);
}

function getOrderAmount() {
  return 10;
}


function calculateShippingAndHandling(orderAmount) {
  if (orderAmount <= 25) {
    return 1.5;
  } else {
    return orderAmount * 10 / 100;
  }
}
```

This would alert the total amount of the order - note however that getOrderAmount returns a static value. This is a quick-and-dirty way of getting things to work. What I leave to you is to research how to take an HTML element such as an input (text box) and get the value of that item, to use as the parameter to calculateShippingAndHandling. You also need to wire up the alertTotalAmount function to the onClick event of something like a button or other HTML element.

Comment: Thanks I think I am starting to get the main idea of how to start it. When it comes to the text box is it suppose to come up within the alert box. For example you write in the purchase price first than add the shipping and handling to anything less than 25 and it will come up the answer within the alert box. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Should I add to the alert box this formula; The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. Because it states it in the assignment if you could go back and reread it.

Comment: I don't think so - the text box would be, at least as far as I would think, just like the one you're typing in right now. So you'd put <input id="orderAmount" /> as an HTML element -- and a <button onclick="alertTotalAmount();" />

Comment: When I read it, it's just telling you what amount you are to use to calculate. That doesn't need to be part of the alert box. The alert box is just the total value..

Comment: For some reason it is not letting me to post it so I will break it down. <html>
<head>
<title>Shipping</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function alertTotalAmount () { 
var orderAmount= prompt("get orderAmount()");
var shippingAndHandling= prompt("calculateShippingAndHandling"(orderAmount));
var totalAmount=alertorderAmount + shippingAndHandling;
<input id= "orderAmount"/>
<button onclick= "alertTotalAmount ();"/>
alert(totalAmount);
}

Comment: function getorderAmount () {
return 10;
}
function calculateshippingAndHandling (orderAmount){
if (orderAmount <=25){
return 1.5;
}else{
return orderAmount * 10 / 100;
}
}
<input id= "orderAmount"/>
<button onclick= "alert TotalAmount ();"/>
alert(totalAmount);
</script>
</body>
</html>   I add some in from what you wrote please help me and tell me where did I go wrong. How should I write the code?

Comment: Please help thhis is what I have it is due today. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculating Shipping and Handling</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//IF YOUR PURCHASE TOTAL IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 25 ADD 1.5 SHIPING AND HANDLING 
//OTHERWISE ADD 10 TO PURCHASED TOTAL PRICE. 
function MsgBox(totalAmount){
alert(totalAmount)}
function totalAmount (){

Comment: alert(totalAmount)}
 var purchaseTotal= totalAmount;
 var percent= 10;
 if (purchaseTotal >25);
 {
  salesPrice= purchaseTotal * 10 / 100;
  document.write("Your total price is" + salesprice);
 }
 else 
 { 
 if (purchaseTotal <=25);
  salesPrice= purchaseTotal + 1.5;
  document.write("Your total price is" + salesprice);
 }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <form>
 Your total is
 <input name= orderAmount type= text />
 <input name= "submit" type= Button value="Total" onclick= "MsgBox(form.orderAmount.value)" />
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Alert dialog boxes are easy in JavaScript:

```
alert("Hello world");
```

Comment: Sorry about that this is what I have: <script type="text/javascript>

Comment: I don't know why it keeps on doing that okay I'll try this again.    <script type="text/javascript> var salesPrice= ("enter purchase charge"); var salesShipping=("enter amount of shipping charge"); alert(salesShipping + "<=25 salesPrice"); </script>

Comment: Can anyone write me examples that deals with my issue?